# Utility to encode any text file into Javascript file as a concatenation of strings

Tags: javascript, sed, awk

Many times we come across instances where we have a certain text file that we want to ship with our Javascript code. Instead of hosting that text file separately on server, it makes sense to write each line of that file into Javascript strings and concatenate them to create a string at runtime.

A typical example is shader code. Three.js code has many example of shader code files embedded as strings inside Javascript code.

Is there any standard/mature utility that can do it? i.e. take the text file as input and generate .js file as output.

Or should I just write a small script of my own? (If someone can give a pithy `awk`/`sed` command, that would be interesting too)

Comment: Read the file as a string and JSON-encode that. Use your favourite scripting language for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Usage: <scriptname> <input-text-file> <output-js-file>
{
  echo "var file_contents ="
  sed 's/"/\\"/g; s/^/"/; s/$/" +/' "$1"
  echo '"";'
} > "$2"
```

Comment: @jayesh, make sure to quote the $1 and $2 variables

Answer (score 1):

15 lines of python should do the trick

```
#Matthew Downey, 2/18/2014
#jsConvert.py
import sys
if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print "Usage:", sys.argv[0], "<inputfile.txt> <outputFile.js> <varName>"
    exit()
f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
jsCode = '"' + lines[0].replace("\n", "\\n") + '"'
for line in lines[1:]:
    line = line.replace("\n", "\\n")
    jsCode = jsCode + ' + ' + '"' + line + '"'
jsCode =  "var " + sys.argv[3] + " = " + jsCode + ";\n"
f = open(sys.argv[2], "a")
f.write(jsCode)
f.close()
```

If I run

> python jsConvert.py test.txt outPut.js questionText

This will take a text file *test.txt* containing the literal text of your question and make a file outPut.js that looks like this:

```
var questionText = "Many times we come across instances where we have a certain text file that we want to ship with our Javascript code. Instead of hosting that text file separately on server, it makes sense to write each line of that file into Javascript strings and concatenate them to create a string at runtime.\n" + "\n" + "A typical example is shader code. Three.js code has many example of shader code files embedded as strings inside Javascript code.\n" + "\n" + "Is there any standard/mature utility that can do it? i.e. take the text file as input and generate .js file as output.\n" + "\n" + "Or should I just write a small script of my own? (If someone can give a pithy awk/sed command, that would be interesting too)";
```

Since it appends if you keep feeding text files into the same output file it will just generate multiple variables containing the text you need.

Hope this helps!